# Versioning and routing for single-page-app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

#### Background

I'm working on a an educational JavaScript application/site (SPA) that will eventually have 1000s of dynamic urls that I'd like to make crawlable.

---

I'm now researching how to implement **versioning, routing and seo (and i18n)**.
My general idea is to use hashbangs and have resources like:

```
example.com/#!/v1?page=story1&country=denmark&year=1950
```

The "page" parameter here decides which controllers/views that need to be loaded and the subsequent parameters could instruct controllers to load corresponding content.

**Versioning** of parameters could then be handled by just replacing the "v1" part of the url - and have a specific route handler mapping deprecated parameters for each version.

**SEO** would be improved by having node.js or other backend delivering an "escaped fragment" version of the content.

**i18n** should probably be handled by node.js as well? This way, what gets delivered to the crawler is already translated?

1. Is this a viable approach to making a Single-page-application versioned and crawlable?
2. I'm using Backbone.js now, what would you add to the mix to help out with the above?

Comment: Any specific reason to use hashbangs instead of HTML5 history API?

Comment: @Kos: What would the benefits be of using the HTML5 history API? I think the key-value approach is clear enough and with it I don't have to set up any server redirects for the pretty urls? Please show an example using the above URL, and I might see your point. Thanks.

Comment: history api could be: example.com/v1/story/denmark/1950 I know expressjs (built on node) can handle this route by app.get('/v1/:page/:country/:year') and you can access the page/country/year variables in your route.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisBiscardi. It however seems complicated to keep track of the ordering of these parameters - but perhaps I'm missing something? What if I have 15 parameters and I'd like to change some of them when i bump the version of the application? Will the history API still be the right solution or should I stick to order-independent key-value pairs?

Comment: Maybe what I mean is what is described in this article: http://www.battlehorse.net/page/2011/02/12/html5history.html - "I'm still stuck with hash tag serialization" even if I'd use the history api for primary state pages. Problem is my primary state ("page") and secondary state ("hash") should have equal weight - i.e. what they encode is equally important to a crawler. So why not skip the fab History API and just use a good-old hashbang for all parameters??  @ChrisBiscardi: Please try to convince me otherwise :)

Comment: see below for my attempt at convincing you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Hell no. (well it could work, but designing your application from the ground up with hashbangs is a bad idea)

2) node.js and backbone are a good combination. Personally I like express for routing/templating on the server.

--The argument against hashbangs:There is so much good information on the web that I will defer to them.

here: http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs

here: http://www.pixelflips.com/blog/do-clean-urls-still-matter/

and this wonderful library: https://github.com/browserstate/History.js/

and this wiki page from that library: https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/wiki/Intelligent-State-Handling

Than check out this chrome extension that will ajax StackOverflow(or any other site with normal urls) using that library: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oikegcanmmpmcmbkdopcfdlbiepmcebg

Are 15 parameters absolutely necessary? Put the content parameters(page, country) in the url and the presentational (ie: sortby=author) in the query string.

in response to "You are still stuck with hash tag serialization" I give this:

every route should point to a valid resource location. ie: /v1/page/denmark/some-slug-for-post should be a resource location and when you change it to a new post/page, that should be a resource location too. What I'm saying is that if you can't use the url to bookmark the page, than the implementation is broken.

Also, are you planning on breaking all your links with every version? I'm not sure why you're including the version in the url.

I hope this helps.

Comment: History.js has a pretty serious SEO problem for users with old browsers.  Links like http://balupton.github.com/history.js/demo/?state=2#?state=1&_suid=132079649448209501852189437323 will return the wrong content to a search engine and suffer from all the same problems as hashbangs.  I would definitely not recommend this as a magic solution.

Comment: didn't say it was magic, you still have to set up all of your content to be accessible from the urls, in the demo you'll notice that the initial state is always an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to number 1, the requirement is that all "pages" have a unique URL and can be found and viewed without JavaScript.

You MUST make a robots.txt that lists all your unique URLs or have a site map somewhere so the crawlers can find all URLs

I'm not sure exactly what yo mean by SEO in this context.  It seems like you are suggesting you will give different content to the crawlers than to the browsers.  Typically not a great idea unless your site is so dynamic there is no other way.

Comment: Thanks @Hogan. As you know, with a very dynamic SPA, viewing sites without JavaScript is not always an option. So my remaining options are probably 1) To render more (incl. doing i18n) server-side, using for example, node.js and hence be able to show both user & crawler same content. 2) To make use of a special hashbang pipeline as described here: http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: @dani - This is exactly why node.js is popular -- it offers a one-code solution - that is - when crawler requests you run js before you send, when browser requests you send js code and let the local machine do the work.